# SAS tagsets.tableeditor proc print free text

Tags: sas, sas-ods

I'm making a few tables using tableeditor and to print table I'm using `proc print` (because of using `web_tabs` option, can't use `proc report` because then there is problem with web tabs (dont know why?)). So, I want to make first web_tabs only with information-free text - like date, time, help etc. 
So, Is there any option to put free text? I know that I can use title tile2 footnote etc.( max=10) but I don't want to create any table on this tab. Or is there any way to create blank/ invisible table? If yes, i can create such a, and then put all in title and footnote.

Comment: Does `ODS TEXT` work in this context?  That's normally the way you add free text.  `ODS TEXT="some text...";`

Comment: no, in tagset.tableeditor it does not work..

Answer (score 0):

Six years later... you can leverage the power of [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and zero configuration [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) to enhance the HTML output experience.

Create a custom style that uses `prehtml` to load the JavaScript libraries and `posthtml` to *convert* the SAS generated tables to DataTables:

```
proc template;
  define style DataTables;   /* name of style to specify when opening ODS HTML */
    parent=styles.htmlblue;  /* name of style to use for thematic desire */

    /* JavaScript to be injected into destination */
    style body from body /
      prehtml=
'
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script 
  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
  charset="utf8"></script>
'
      posthtml=
'
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $(".table").DataTable();
});
</script>
'
    ;  
  end;
run;


ods html path='c:\temp' file="dt.html" style=DataTables;

proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;

proc report data=sashelp.class;
run;

data air;
  set sashelp.air;
  year = year(date);
run;

proc tabulate data=air contents='tab';
  class year date / order=data;
  format date monname3.;
  var air;
  table year, date=''*air=''*sum=''*f=4. / nocellmerge;
run;

ods _all_ close;
```